# Laplace and fourier transform of one sided decaying exponential

Tags: laplace-transform, fourier-transform

I am stuck on this problem as i have no idea what will be the limits..
and also don't know how to start from till the end.

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NYhex.png) This is question: [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NYhex.png)

Answer (score 2):

The Laplace Transform of $f(t)=e^{-at}u(t)$ is given by

$$\mathscr{L}\{e^{-at}u(t)\}=\int_0^\infty e^{-at}e^{-st}\,dt=\frac{1}{s+a}$$

The Fourier Transform of $f(t)$ is given by

$$\mathscr{F}\{e^{-at}u(t)\}=\int_0^\infty e^{-at}e^{i\omega t}\,dt=\frac{1}{a-i\omega}$$

Comment: this is not corect

Comment: What is correct then?

Comment: table says: for fourier it should be 1/a+jw

Comment: How is the FT defined?  Is it as simple as $j\to -i$?  That is, are you defining the FT as $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(t)e^{-j\omega t}\,dt?$$

Comment: f(t) = { 0 , t<0          e^-t , t>0  }

Comment: No; I'm asking how you define the FT of $f$?  Is it  $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(t)e^{-j\omega t}\,dt?$$If so, can you not immediately see we have the same answer upon replacing $j$ with $-i$?  Furthermore, just carry out the almost trivial integral.  What do you  obtain??

Comment: i have no idea i just look upon the table

Comment: Well, I suggest that you learn how to integrate simple functions and refrain from relying on a table, especially if it is causing you problems.  That way, you are in charge and not the table.

Comment: i got it you are right...it is 1/a-iw thanks

Comment: can you please also explain about growing exponential??

Comment: For the growing exponential, the Laplace Transform converges to $\frac{1}{s-a}$ for $s>a$ and diverges otherwise.  The Fourier Transform diverges.